# Exportar resultado de consulta sql server para arquivo txt em servidor apache automaticamente

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, txt

Eu faço a seguinte consulta do meu servidor apache em um banco SQL SERVER:

```
<?php

// Dados do banco
$dbhost   = "192.168.0.100";    #Nome do host
$db       = "DATABASE";         #Nome do banco de dados
$user     = "root";                 #Nome do usuáo
$password = "root";             #Senha do usuáo

@mssql_connect($dbhost,$user,$password) or die("Nãfoi possíl a conexãcom o servidor!");
@mssql_select_db("$db") or die("Nãfoi possíl selecionar o banco de dados!");

$instrucaoSQL = "SELECT  
                    A.CODIGO     AS COD,
                    B.chapa      AS CHAPA,
                    A.nome       AS NOME,
                    REPLICATE('0', 11 - LEN(A.cpf)) + RTrim(A.cpf) AS CPF,
                    B.CODFILIAL  AS LOJA
                FROM
                    PPESSOA AS 
                        A LEFT OUTER  JOIN PFUNC as B on 
                                A.CODIGO = b.CODPESSOA                              
                                WHERE B.CODSITUACAO<>'D'
                                  ORDER BY CHAPA";
$consulta = mssql_query($instrucaoSQL);
$numRegistros = mssql_num_rows($consulta);

echo "Esta tabela contém $numRegistros registros!\n<hr>\n";

if ($numRegistros!=0) {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        echo $row['COD']."-".$row['CHAPA']."-".$row['NOME']."-".$row['CPF']."-".$row['LOJA']."\n<br>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Preciso salvar o resultado dentro de uma pasta em um arquivo .txt em meu servidor apache,exemplo:

```
/var/www/html/sistema/export/resultado.txt
```

Como poderia fazer esse tipo de processo automaticamente?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` pode ajudar para criar o arquivo.

Comment: file_put_contents é uma função que substitui fope fwrite e fclose, segundo  um artigo o fwrite trabalha mais rápido, e melhor com arquivos grandes, do que file_put_contents , existe um tópico sobre isto no stackoverflow em inglês com o artigo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415958/whats-faster-file-put-contents-fopen-fwrite-fclose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isto você irá precisar de 3 funções php:

```
fopen, fwrite, fclose
```

**fopen:** [php.net/fopen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)

```
$file = fopen(string $filename , string $mode);
```

**$filename**: Caminho até o arquivo a ser utilizado

**$mode**: Modo no qual irá trabalhar com este arquivo. O `fopen` irá criar automaticamente o arquivo de txt caso ele não existe, caso existe você deve decidir se o que irá colocar dentro do arquivo deve ser no começo ou no final, isso você poderá editar pela `$mode`, [Saiba mais!](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)

Depois de aberto o seu arquivo, você precisar escrever nele, como dito anteriormente, o que irá escrever irá aparecer no começo ou no final do arquivo, dependendo do `$mode` que utilizou na função `$fopen`. Para escrever no arquivo utilizar `fwrite`.

**fwrite**: [php.net/fwrite](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php)

```
fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
```

Depois de escrito, você precisa fechar o arquivo em questão, utilizando a função `fclose`

**fclose**: [php.net/fclose](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fclose.php)

```
bool fclose ( resource $handle )
```

Exemplo: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp)

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Adaptando ao seu código ficaria assim:

```
<?php

// Dados do banco
$dbhost   = "192.168.0.100";    #Nome do host
$db       = "DATABASE";         #Nome do banco de dados
$user     = "root";                 #Nome do usuáo
$password = "root";             #Senha do usuáo

@mssql_connect($dbhost,$user,$password) or die("Nãfoi possíl a conexãcom o servidor!");
@mssql_select_db("$db") or die("Nãfoi possíl selecionar o banco de dados!");

$instrucaoSQL = "SELECT  
                    A.CODIGO     AS COD,
                    B.chapa      AS CHAPA,
                    A.nome       AS NOME,
                    REPLICATE('0', 11 - LEN(A.cpf)) + RTrim(A.cpf) AS CPF,
                    B.CODFILIAL  AS LOJA
                FROM
                    PPESSOA AS 
                        A LEFT OUTER  JOIN PFUNC as B on 
                                A.CODIGO = b.CODPESSOA                              
                                WHERE B.CODSITUACAO<>'D'
                                  ORDER BY CHAPA";
$consulta = mssql_query($instrucaoSQL);
$numRegistros = mssql_num_rows($consulta);

echo "Esta tabela contém $numRegistros registros!\n<hr>\n";

if ($numRegistros!=0) {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        $string = $row['COD']."-".$row['CHAPA']."-".$row['NOME']."-".$row['CPF']."-".$row['LOJA']."\n<br>\n";
        $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
        fwrite($file,$string);
        fclose($file);
        echo $string;
    }
}

?>
```

**EDIT**:
Como você precisar gravar muitos registros com uma única chamada mysql a forma correta de se utilizar seria:

```
if ($numRegistros!=0) {
    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        $string = $row['COD']."-".$row['CHAPA']."-".$row['NOME']."-".$row['CPF']."-".$row['LOJA']."\n<br>\n";
        fwrite($file,$string);
        echo $string;
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

> Utilizando o `$mode` "w" irá abrir o arquivo e escrever no início dele

Comment: Deu quase certo, porque esta gravando somente o ultimo registro, são muitos,preciso que grave todos. O que poderia ser ?

Comment: Provavelmente porque o arquivo está sendo aberto e fechado rápido de mais dentro do loop de registros, não tenho absoluta certeza, então eu editei minha resposta de forma que o arquivo seja aberto uma única vez e escrito todos os registros do loop, e depois fechado, tente desta maneira

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado, foi muito interessante,vou estudar mais sobre isso. Abraço !

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_put_contents()` para criar o arquivo passando uma string (`$conteudo`) que terá todos os campos da consulta seperados por `-` quem faz isso `implode()`

```
$conteudo .= '';  
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $conteudo .= implode($row, '-') .PHP_EOL;  
}

file_put_contents('consulta.txt', $conteudo);
```