# Exporta consulta do banco para txt com php

Tags: php, mysql, txt

```
//Arquivo txt
$arquivo = "email.txt";

//abrir arquivo txt 

$arq = fopen($arquivo,"w");

//faz consulta no banco de dados

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");

$cabecalho = "Emails extraidos\n";

fwrite($arq, $cabecalho);


while($escrever = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $conteudo = $escrever ['email'];

    //escreve no arquivo txt

    fwrite($arq,$conteudo);
}

//fecha o arquivo
fclose($arq);
```

Erro que está dando
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aonde você conecta ao seu banco de dados?

Comment: $dsn = "mysql:dbname=blog;host=127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

try{
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Falhou a conexão: ".$e->getMessage();

}

Comment: tentou com `mysli_query` ?

Comment: a função `mysql` já está deprecada, de uma olhada  nas respostas dessa outra pergunta, podem te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644318/deprecated-mysql-query

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exportar resultado de consulta sql server para arquivo txt em servidor apache automaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177690/exportar-resultado-de-consulta-sql-server-para-arquivo-txt-em-servidor-apache-au)

Comment: com mysqli_query ERRO:  Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\pagina lan page\config.php on line 24

Comment: como você está utilizando o `wamp` é provável que você esteja utilizando a versão `PHP7.1` no qual as funções `mysql` foram descontinuadas: aqui tem outro usuário com o mesmo problema : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173037/como-resolver-o-erro-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: Resolvi aqui galera muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql\_query()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234402/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1):

**Resolvido**
**Código Funcionando**

```
//Conectar na banco
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "senha", "nome do banco");

//Arquivo txt
$arquivo = "email.txt";

//abrir arquivo txt 
$arq = fopen($arquivo,"w");

//faz consulta no banco de dados
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");

$cabecalho = "Emails extraidos\n";

fwrite($arq, $cabecalho);


while($escrever = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $conteudo = $escrever ['email']."\n";

    //escreve no arquivo txt

    fwrite($arq,$conteudo);
}

//fecha o arquivo
fclose($arq);
```

Comment: Se possível de uma breve explicação sobre como resolveu o problema dessa maneira outros usuários podem também encontrar a solução.

Comment: Adicionei: $link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "senha", "nome do banco");
Mudei os mysql por mysqli e coloquei  $link no mysqli_query:
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");